# How to parse the header files of the pcap file?

Tags: python, pcap

I have installed python(x,y) 2.7.5.1 and dpkt 1.7 win32.exe module in Windows 8.
My input dataset is the .pcap files downloaded from CAIDA.  I want to parse the pcap file to see the IP and TCP headers of the packets as shown below.

```
Ethernet(src='\x00\x1a\xa0kUf', dst='\x00\x13I\xae\x84,', data=IP(src='\xc0\xa8\n\n',
off=16384, dst='C\x17\x030', sum=25129, len=52, p=6, id=51105, data=TCP(seq=9632694,
off_x2=128, ack=3382015884, win=54, sum=65372, flags=17, dport=80, sport=56145)))
```

The code used is

```
f = open('test.pcap') pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
for ts, buf in pcap:
  eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
  print eth
```

But Iam getting like below only:  It is not showing the IP and TCP headers.  What is the reason? How to parse the header files of the pcap file?

```
Ethernet(src='\x00\x00\xcd\x01k7', dst='E\x00\x00<\xda\xd3', type=10315, data='Y\xacG~\xde@\x08\x00\xf8\xb3K\xa4\x05\x00')
```

Pls help me as soon as possible..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is giving the full ethernet packet which internally contains Ip, and TCP packet.

```
In [87]: data
Out[87]: Ethernet(src='\x00\x1a\xa0kUf', dst='\x00\x13I\xae\x84,', data=IP(src='\xc0\xa8\n\n', off=16384, dst='C\x17\x030', sum=25129, len=52, p=6, id=51105, data=TCP(seq=9632694, off_x2=128, ack=3382015884L, win=54, sum=65372, flags=17, dport=80, sport=56145)))
```

you can access the source mac address from Ethernet packet as

```
In [88]: data.src
Out[88]: '\x00\x1a\xa0kUf'
```

Access the Ethernet packet data(which is IP pkt internally contains TCP pkt) as

```
In [89]: data.data
Out[89]: IP(src='\xc0\xa8\n\n', off=16384, dst='C\x17\x030', sum=25129, len=52, p=6, id=51105, data=TCP(seq=9632694, off_x2=128, ack=3382015884L, win=54, sum=65372, flags=17, dport=80, sport=56145))
```

Access the source Ip as

```
In [90]: data.data.src
Out[90]: '\xc0\xa8\n\n'
```

Access the TCP data as

```
In [91]: data.data.data
Out[91]: TCP(seq=9632694, off_x2=128, ack=3382015884L, win=54, sum=65372, flags=17, dport=80, sport=56145)
```

You can modify your code as,

The code used is

```
f = open('test.pcap') pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
for ts, buf in pcap:
  eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
  print eth
  eth.data          # To get IP pkt
  eth.data.data     # To get TCP pkt
```

Comment: I am getting error when accessing eth.data.data as it has no attribute data.

>>> eth.data
'Y\xacG~\xde@\x08\x00\xf8\xb3K\xa4\x05\x00'

>>> eth.data.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Maybe It is not a TCP pkt, It maybe a ARP/ICMP pkt, you have to add proper checks for TCP/UDP/ARP/ICMP pkts.

Comment: When opening the input CAIDA pcap file in Wireshark, it includes both the TCP and ICMP packets.  We can see the header informations such as timetolive, flags etc in Wireshark, but how to access these data using programming via Python or any other Programming language available?
[ In the stack overflow of some other similar questions  it is shown that pcap file does not have ethernet as its layer 2 protocol is the reason for the attribute data doesnot exist.  If so, then what to do? ]